# How many servers or what specs do I need to handle 100000 users?

Tags: load-balancing, scaling

I was just wondering how many servers or what specs should have my server (or servers) if I want to handle 100000 users considering that each user will login every three days. (10 times a month)

EDIT: The users will mainly browse pages, post forms, upload a small number pictures. It will involve a quite big mysql database.

If I tell you:
Storage: 250GB 10K RPM RAID-10
Dedicated RAM: 8GB
Bandwidth: 3TB

Do you think a website on this server will run smoothly?
Should I go for more RAM (16GB) or can I go for less (4GB)?
Do you think I should get many servers?

And the real question is: how can I technically know what should I go for (as options and specs)?

Considering that the 100000 users is my initial and final traffic (so it’s not progressive and it won't grow bigger) taking one smaller and growing depending on the needs can’t be an option ( :) ).

Advance thanks

PS: This is NOT for a social network website, :) (I've read some already posted questions)

Comment: And what will these users do when they login every three days? We have no way to answer this question unless we know what load they are putting on the server. Are they reading a single static web page or are they using a complex web app that talks to a database? If so what load testing have you done with your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why is growing not an option ? (within reason). There's often not "enough and not enough" situations in these matters, only an acceptable response time and load level.

Largely it depends on how heavy your code is and what type of work it needs to do. I wouldn't totally write off putting out a best guess that's slightly conservative and ramping it up if the site performs under what you want.

That said, don't get a single $400 machine from new egg and expect that plan to work.

I'd say (given the lack of clearly defined use case data or expected load levels) to try and keep your options open as much as possible in terms of removing unforseen bottlenecks.